# Passing escape sequences to shells within ansi-term in Emacs

Tags: terminal, emacs, postgresql, ansi-term

In a regular terminal (e.g. iTerm2 on OS X) I can connect to a database, e.g.

```
> psql ....
```

and then, as I type my command in `psql`, e.g.

```
$ select foo from bar
```

I can move around (as I type psql commands) using the standard `Alt+b` and `Alt+f`.

However, if I try to do this in a shell within Emacs (`ansi-term`), it doesn't work.

More specifically, if I start a shell (e.g. Bash) within `ansi-term`, the keystrokes `Alt+b` and `Alt+f` work fine in the Unix shell (in this case, Bash), **BUT** if I then drop into `psql` from within the shell, the keystrokes `Alt+b` nor `Alt+f` stop working (the keystrokes won't move the cursor, and I can't keep typing commands properly anymore)

Why is this? And how can fix this behavior?

### Update 1:

I narrowed the problem and the line in my `.zshrc` that causes this behavior is the following one:

```
TERM=xterm-256color
```

I have this line because its's the best solution that I found to fix the problem that I report in this thread:
[Emacs multi-term not displaying special characters correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303611/emacs-multi-term-not-displaying-special-characters-correctly)

### Update 2 (solution, but why?):

I found the solution in this thread: [Weird character zsh in emacs terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918910/weird-character-zsh-in-emacs-terminal). As the top answer says, I had to create `eterm-color` `terminfo` by using following command: (note that the `terminfo` path may be different from your system)

```
# If you use Cocoa Emacs or Carbon Emacs
tic -o ~/.terminfo /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/etc/e/eterm-color.ti
```

Comment: Do you have anything relevant in your `~/.inputrc`? I just tried with `ansi-term`, `mysql` and `bash` (and `zsh`) and it works fine. I don't have access to a psql database, perhaps something specific to its shell?

Comment: Thanks @terdon, but I don't have an `.inputrc` file in my home directory. Also - I am using Zsh. Actually, I **don't** have this problem in bash! Hmmm

Comment: Strange, I tested with both bash and zsh and in both cases it worked fine on a VM with Ubuntu server. I'd never used `zsh` o that machine before, I installed it just to try this out, so everything would be in its default state. Perhaps you are remapping these commands to something in your `~/.zshrc`?

Comment: Thanks @terdon - What commands would be equivalent to the changes you mentioned in `.inputrc` for Zsh? I am afraid that my `.zshrc` (and Zsh init files) are quite large at this point.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea :) I just thought that .inputrc would be a place to check. Try explicitly setting those shortcuts in `.inputrc`. For example, this sets Ctrl+Left to backward-word (same as Alt-B): `"\e[1;5D": backward-word`

Comment: Your question is not clear: where are you using bash and where are you using zsh? What happens if you tell ansi-term to use `psql` itself as a shell? What happens if you move your `.bashrc`, `.zshrc` and `.inputrc` out of the way?

Comment: Thanks @Gilles I edited the OP - hopefully the question is clearer now. I will experiment with moving `.zshrc` out of the way next.

Comment: @Gilles - I narrowed the problem to this statement `TERM=xterm-256color` in my `.zshrc`. See my update in the OP for the details.

Comment: I'd say that `TERM=xterm-256color` is just wrong — you're lying to psql and thus getting what you deserve — but I don't understand why it fixes your other problem.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles - I have updated the OP with a second update that solved my problem using the answer to another thread. I am not quite sure why it fixes my problem, so I didn't provide it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Emacs wiki, the recommended `TERM` setting for ansi-term is ["eterm-color"](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-eterm-color).  That terminal description is provided by ncurses; you probably would have to use the package with the complete terminfo database for platforms which make a distinction, e.g., Debian with `ncurses-base` and `ncurses-term`.

The `eterm-color` description provides 16 colors, which still appears to be the current state of the Emacs code.  Aside from that, the description for `xterm-256color` includes escape sequences which Emacs is unlikely to handle properly.  Using `infocmp`, there are several capabilities which differ and could produce a problem in (a) cursor movement and (b) scrolling.  Here are the interesting lines:

```
    ech: NULL, '\E[%p1%dX'.
    flash: NULL, '\E[?5h$<100/>\E[?5l'.
    hpa: NULL, '\E[%i%p1%dG'.
    hts: NULL, '\EH'.
    indn: NULL, '\E[%p1%dS'
    rin: NULL, '\E[%p1%dT'.
    rmam: NULL, '\E[?7l'.
    rmcup: NULL, '\E[?1049l'.
    rmkx: NULL, '\E[?1l\E>'.
    rmm: NULL, '\E[?1034l'
    sitm: NULL, '\E[3m'.
    smacs: NULL, '\E(0'.
    smam: NULL, '\E[?7h'.
    smcup: NULL, '\E[?1049h'.
    smkx: NULL, '\E[?1h\E='.
    smm: NULL, '\E[?1034h'.
    tbc: NULL, '\E[3g'.
    vpa: NULL, '\E[%i%p1%dd'.
```

For instance:

- `hpa` for instance works in xterm to move the cursor horizontally.
- `smm` and `rmm` control meta mode (which is relevant to the mention of "alt" keys: see the description of meta in [terminfo(5)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Miscellaneous)).
- `indn` and `rin` are used for vertical scrolling

When the terminal capabilities and terminal description do not agree, you can see odd things happening.  In a quick test of Emacs 24.5, ansi-term implements *none* of those features; all are likely to be used by full-screen programs, and some (such as `hpa`) would be used by command-line programs.

Further reading:

- [AnsiTermHints](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTermHints) (Emacs wiki)
- [Modifying ansi-term colors in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635332/modifying-ansi-term-colors-in-emacs)